# Reducing the height of NSProgressIndicator from interface builder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I am new to cocoa development.

Is there a way to reduce the height of a NSProgressIndicator from interface builder? I see the height is grayed out on 19 pt there!

I see also a size property with small and regular but what about I creating my own size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not working with NSProgressIndicator but I worked a lot with UIProgressView (iOS analog of NSProgressIndicator). And it is impossible to change UIProgressView's height neither in IB neither by changing its frame property.

But there is a nice workaround! In iOS you can use transform property to change the height. Following will reduce height by 50%:

```
_progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 0.5f);
```

Maybe you can use the same workaround for NSProgressIndicator.

Comment: ok thanks, but that cannot be done by using interface builder, isn't it?

Comment: @RubberDuck yes, it is impossible to do it in IB.